# Arduino: How to show Serial.print value to any textbox or Notepad

Tags: c++, c, arduino

So I saw an Arduino program that will show an RFID value to the serial monitor, I just want to know how can I also show it to any textbox or Notepad or wherever. For example, I opened a Notepad or Word, when I swiped the RFID keychain, it suppose to show the value there. Here's the code I got:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9
#define SS_PIN          10
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
SPI.begin();
mfrc522.PCD_Init();
pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
RfidScan();
}

void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : ""); // The value I want to show
Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
}
digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(7, LOW);
delay(1000);
Serial.print("\n");
}

void RfidScan()
{
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
return;

if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
return;
dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stty](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty).

Here's a sample :

```
stty -F /dev/my_serial_port <baud_rate> cs8 cread clocal > filename
```

Here you redirect all the output from the serial port to a file. To print out the contents as they come in you can use

```
tail -f filename
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this .using a 3rd party tool will be easy to get the serial output. or else you can try following link. I have explained what you need to do.

**Try This**

[Follow this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/54/saving-arduino-sensor-data-to-a-text-file)

What you need is **PrintWriter**.

Import PrintWriter :

```
PrintWriter output;
```

Instantiate output object in the setup() method :

```
output = createWriter( "data.txt" );
```

Writes the data to text file

```
output.println( value );
```

This "value" data can be retrieved from serial

```
String value = serial.readString();
```

Finally flush the data and close the file.

```
output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
output.close();  // Finishes the file
```